# Terraform - Using Local Command Result as an Variable for tf file

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to use local-exec to generate an output for a variable inside of Terraform .tf file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

data-external feature of Terraform has helped me

## cat owner.sh

```
jq -n --arg username $(git config user.name) '{"username": $username}'
```

## The config part which must be added on instance_create.tf files;

```
data "external" "owner_tag_generator" {
  program = ["bash", "/full/path/of/owner.sh"]
}

output "owner" {
  value = "${data.external.owner_tag_generator.result}"
}

tags {
...
CreatorName = "${data.external.owner_tag_generator.result.username}"
...
}
```

Comment: You'll want to surround your command substitution in jq with double-quotes, otherwise you'll get a `jq: compile error` if there's a comma in the value.  For example, if the username is in the format {LAST}, {FIRST} {MIDDLE}.  It should be: `jq -n --arg username "$(git config user.name)" '{"username": $username}'`